# When a select cursor is created by foxpro, it shows the '1900-01-01' dates as null

Tags: date, db2, cursor, ibm-midrange, foxpro

I´m using vfp6 and iseries communicator. I have a table with a date field. This table have several records with the '1900-01-01' value but, when I make a select to that table from foxpro, those cells show a NULL value. The same select on the communicator shows the dates just fine. My regional config is day/month/year and this is the same settings at the odbc config. I've also set SET CENTURY ON on the vfp application, but still the same. We have other clients running with no issue so I don't know what could it be the problem.

Comment: Some foxpro clients work OK with these dates, and at least one foxpro client fails with these dates?

Comment: Indeed. Now I've used a NVL(field, date(1900,1,1)) to tackle the issue but still, it seems strange

Comment: That's not a programming matter. It's configuration. When you have a working machine and a failing machine then systematic elimination of the differences between them will reveal the culprit.  Stackoverflow is for programming questions and not configuration matters.